# Cannot Insert ID into MySQL Table

Tags: php, mysql

What I am trying to do is allow the user to create a table and I want to add the userID of the user into the first line of the table so I can access it later. However, when trying to insert the ID, I keep getting an error message saying I cannot add it. Here is my code:

```
<?php
    @ $db = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'secret', 'Pokemon'); //open db
    if ($db->connect_error) { 
        echo 'ERROR: Could not connect to database, error is '. $db->connect_error;
        exit;
    } else {
        echo 'Successful connection established<br />';
    }

    $deckName = stripslashes($_POST['deckName']); //sql sanitize for each input.
    $deckName = $db->real_escape_string($deckName);

    $checkQuery = "SELECT userID FROM userInfo WHERE userEmail = ?";

    $checkStmt = $db->prepare($checkQuery);

    $checkStmt->bind_param("s", $SESSION['userEmail']);

    $checkStmt->execute();

    if ( ($checkStmt->errno <> 0) || ($checkStmt->num_rows > 0) )
    {
    $checkStmt->close();
    echo 'ERROR: Something is wrong';
    exit;
    }

    $res = $checkStmt->get_result();

    $row = $res->fetch_assoc();

    $checkStmt->close();

    $query = "CREATE TABLE `".$deckName."` (userID int(3), pokeID int(3), pokeName varchar(20), quantity int(1), 
    PRIMARY KEY (userID) )";

    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);

    $stmt->execute();

    if ($stmt->errno <> 0)
    {
      $stmt->close();
      $db->close();
      echo 'ERROR: Could not create table';
      exit;
    }

    $stmt->close();

    $query = "INSERT INTO `".$deckName."` (userID) VALUES(?)";

    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);

    $stmt->bind_param("i", $row['userID']);

    $stmt->execute();

    if ($stmt->errno <> 0)
    {
      $stmt->close();
      $db->close();
      echo 'ERROR: Could not add to database';
      exit;
    }

    $stmt->close();

    $db->close();   


    header("Location: viewCards.php"); 
?>
```

It creates the table, but will not insert the userID. I have looked at this trying to find what the issue is, and I would like a fresh set of eyes to look at it if possible.

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_SESSION['userEmail']` instead of `$SESSION['userEmail']` and there is no `session_start()`

Comment: Thank you very much! Simple overlooked things. Thanks for the fresh set of eyes!